# Como retirar comentários automáticos gerados pelo Compass?

Tags: css3, sass, grunt

Escrevo o código em SCSS, e quando gero o CSS ele vem com comentários de onde está a Class ou ID no meu SCSS.

Alguém sabe como posso retirar esses comentários gerados pelo compass do meu arquivo CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere as configurações no seu *config.rb*.

Você pode definir a variavel `output_style` para `:compressed` por exemplo. No comentário da linha desta variável, por padrão vem escrito outras opções, você pode testar elas para ver qual se encaixa melhor na sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desativar os `line comments`. Eles são geralmente usados pra ajudar a debugar e resolver problemas em projetos grandes, com muitos arquivos SASS.

no *config.rb* você adiciona:

```
line_comments = false
```